# creating some action in webview and showing the result in different part of view in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, events, uiwebview

I have a split view where my master is a table view menu and my detail is UIWebview content view.
Whenever I click on my table cell respective urls are opening in content view , showing the table cell selected.

In one of the content view which is a web page, when I click on a button over there I want to show one of the table view  cell selected in my menu view .

If I use touch events it will happen for all the view ,I want to do this action for that particular button. Any idea how to get this done.

Comment: Did you add the button to the webview?

Comment: No its already there in the web view

Comment: What does button by default do? Does it have any redirection url or something else?

Comment: are you saying that the button is in the webpage that you are loading?

Comment: yeah the button is in the webpage on clicking that button its redirecting to another url, and this url and one of the table view cell url are same ,so whenever the user clicks this button on webpage and redirecting to that url ,I want to show that table view cell as selected

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Button is on the webPage and its opening another webPage. then you can manage your code with using delegate methods of webview

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    // Here you can check the URL
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"your  url"]) {
        // Do something
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: if anyone do the negative marking please also do the comment. so i can understood why?

Comment: I also wonder why sometimes correct answer has a negative mark.

Comment: Any more suggestion on the above question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you correctly, you have uiwebview inside detail view controller. UIWebView has  html buttons, which redirect to some urls. The aim is notify your master controller about such redirections. In that case, I advice you to use one of the delegate methods of [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a), which is

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Inside that method your should notify your master controller. You could use your custom protocol (look at that [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial)) or use [NSNotificationCenter](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) to send notification. To select row you could use method of table view:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

Comment: will you plz explain a lit bit more